# Infinite precision floating point arithmetic

Tags: floating-point

This is a soft question.

I know the whole story with the mantissa as a way of storing floating points, as well as some of the hiccups this story comes with, in terms of errors and so on.

Is storing floating point numbers as a pair of integers ever used? I mean, this is definitely infinite precision, as long as we don't evaluate the fraction. I guess that in terms of memory consumption, fractions are worse, but when actually doing arithmetic, it doesn't get better than with them.

Apart from memory consumption, are there any other problems with this approach?

Comment: This is called [Rational Arithetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_data_type), though there are variations with bounded and unbounded values.

Comment: Some further drawbacks: You can't represent irrationals (sure floating point can also only approximate these ...), and on most modern hardware, floating point operations are very fast, whereas rational arithmetic needs a relatively expensive `gcd` call for most operations (you could of course delay normalizing your numbers in some cases, at the cost of getting even bigger intermediate numbers).

Comment: The main problem of rationals is that the numerator/denominator will be ever growing in long computation chains, making computations more and more expensive in both time and memory. So one way or the other, we will have to perform further approximations and round some results to a reasonable precision...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should clarify, that I don't care about complexity/cost of operations, I am looking at it from a theoretic point of view. As far as irrationals go, these are just sequences of rationals which can be represented by a finite formula, and if not, the number is uncomputable anyway. My question is whether there are problems other than cost.

Comment: @Jason, "I mean, this is definitely infinite precision," , "just sequences of rationals which can be represented by a finite formula", --> Doubtful.  Pi (3.,14....) cannot be exactly expressed as a ratio of 2 integers.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, sequences of rationals. Every irrational is a sequence of rationals.

Comment: If you are aiming at implementing something in the direction of a computer algebra system: These do use rationals, as well as other symbolic representations of numbers. (I don't think "sequence of rational numbers" is a practical way to actually represent a number -- describing this sequence is usually not the shortest way to describe an irrational number. Also comparing numbers for equality needs proving whether these sequences converge to the same number.)

Comment: I hadn't thought of equality. Thanks for the input.